# Python Clock Increment

Tags: python

I have created a clock program that should run on the terminal. but whenever I run it, it always increments the seconds, minutes and hours by 1 every second.

It should only increment the seconds by 1 every second until seconds is 60 then increment the minutes by 1 etc..

I don't know why it outputs 1:1:1 then 2:2:2 then 3:3:3 etc...

```
# Clock
import time
import sys


class Counter:
    count = 0
    name = ""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def Increment(self):
        Counter.count += 1

   def Reset(self):
        Counter.count = 0


class Clock:

    seconds = Counter("Seconds")
    minutes = Counter("Minutes")
    hours = Counter("Hours")

    def Tick(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        Clock.seconds.Increment()

        if Clock.seconds.count >= 60:
            Clock.seconds.Reset()
            Clock.minutes.Increment()
            if Clock.minutes.count >= 60:
                Clock.minutes.Reset()
                Clock.hours.Increment()
                if Clock.hours.count >= 12:
                    Clock.ResetClock()

    def ResetClock(self):
        Clock.seconds.Reset()
        Clock.minutes.Reset()
        Clock.hours.Reset()

    def SetClock(self, seconds, minutes, hours):
        self.hours = hours
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.seconds = seconds

    def ReadClock(self):
        sys.stdout.writelines(" \r Current Time: %d:%d:%d" % (Clock.hours.count, Clock.minutes.count, Clock.seconds.count))


clock = Clock()
while True:
    clock.Tick()
    clock.ReadClock()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have class-level variables instead of instance-level variables in your `Counter` class. This means the variable `count` is shared between your classes, which is why it increments whenever `Increment` is called.

You should have `count` be part of the instance instead of the class:

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.count = 0

    def Increment(self):
        self.count += 1

    def Reset(self):
        self.count = 0
```

Comment: Excellent! thank you! first day using python so I am understanding it more and more now thanks! I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes when it allows.